# How to use a custom method in ggplot2 for fitting smooth line

Tags: r, ggplot2

In normal cases we would have something that resembles

```
ggplot(data=data.frame)+
geom_point(...)+
geom_smooth(...,method="lm")
```

However, I do not want to fit a smooth like using `lm`. I want to use a custom fit, using the `SiZer` package, in particular I want to use the `bent.cable` function from this package.

How can I incorporate this in `ggplot`? I tried:

```
method=SiZer::bent.cable(x=...,y=...)
```

but I get the following error:

> Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`: 'what' must be a function or character string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bent.cable is not like lm, glm etc, where it requires an argument data and so on.. If your purpose is to show the fit, consider something like below:

```
#fit the piecewise first
model <- bent.cable(Arkansas$year,Arkansas$sqrt.mayflies, grid.size=20)
# basic plot
g <- ggplot(Arkansas, aes(x=year,y=sqrt.mayflies)) + geom_point()
print(g)
# get the piecewise prediction
tmp = data.frame(
year <- seq(min(Arkansas$year), max(Arkansas$year), length=200),
sqrt.mayflies <- predict(model,x.grid)
)
g + geom_line(data=tmp,col="blue")
```

[image: Output showing fitted values of bent.cable]

Comment: Thank you for contribution. I am wondering where the shaded errors have gone?

Comment: it's not obvious that there's any built-in method for extracting standard errors of predictions from a `bent_cable` model. Looking at `SiZer:::predict.bent_cable` doesn't suggest *easy* ways of getting the SEs (bootstrapping ...)

Comment: Adding to @BenBolker, most likely you need to bootstrap, calculate the confidence interval and plot it with geom_ribbon. It's not trivial to calculate the standard error of such a fit